# Why are my tkinter widgets not appearing in the order I am expecting after activating the button widget?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, time

```
import tkinter as tk
import time as t
import tkinter 
from tkinter.constants import * 

frame = tkinter.Tk() 

title = frame.title("RickRoll Detector")


label = tkinter.Label(frame, text="RickRoll Detector", border = 40, font = ("Lobster",100, "bold"), anchor = N) 
label.pack(fill=X)
inputtext = tk.Text(frame, height = 5, width = 45)
inputtext.pack(anchor=CENTER)
def inpu():
    inp = inputtext.get(1.0, "end-1c")
    if inp == "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ":
        label1 = tk.Label(frame, text = "Rickroll detected!!", height = 5, width = 20, bg = "#FF0000", font = (20))
        label1.pack()
        t.sleep(5)
    else:
        
        label1 = tk.Label(frame, text = "Safe and Secure", height = 5, width = 20, bg = "#00FF00", font = (20))
        label1.pack()
        t.sleep(5)
        frame.destroy()

button = tk.Button(text = "Enter", command = inpu, height = 3, width = 10, bg = "#0096FF" )

button.pack()

tk.mainloop()
```

According to the order of my python code, if wrong text input is used, a label widget showing `Safe and Secure` should appear for 5 secs and the tkinter window would then be destroyed. Why is this behaviour not happening?

Comment: I want to exit the app after showing result but it won't be possible without t.sleep(5) and frame.destroy()

Comment: Change `tk.mainloop()` to `frame.mainloop()`.  Add `def destroy_window():frame.destroy()` before `def inpu():`. Replace `t.sleep(5)` and `frame.destroy()` with `frame.quit()` and `frame.after(5000, destroy_window)`